# Flutter - automatically launch app from onBackgroundMessage when FCM data message is received for incoming VoIP call

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

My app has a VoIP feature for users, controlled via Firebase (FCM & rtdb).

### My problem:

I'm unable to launch the app when a e.g. **VoIP incoming call** fcm message (notification) arrives. **This is crucial** as showing this only as a popup push notification isn't sufficient. I need to be able to launch the app from [FirebaseMessaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) [onBackgroundMessage](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/usage/#background-messages) [Isolate](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-isolate/Isolate-class.html) function. (see example mcve code below)

Requirements of Isolate (Android specific):

> When received, an isolate is spawned (Android only, iOS/macOS does not require a separate isolate) allowing you to handle messages even when your application is not running.
>
> There are a few things to keep in mind about your background message handler:
>
> 1. It must not be an anonymous function.
> 2. It must be a **top-level function** (e.g. not a class method which requires initialization).

### Sample (MCVE) flutter setup:

Thus, my code is setup to call this Isolate function as required, a simple example is shown below:

```
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  print("Handling a background message: ${message.messageId}");

  // if message.payload.type == "INCOMING_CALL"
  //     LAUNCH APP with INCOMING CALL screen here
}

void main() {
  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

**The problem is** I'm unable to launch the app from the line `LAUNCH APP with INCOMING CALL screen here` mentioned above. I've tried `runApp(MaterialApp(...))` which doesn't launch the app, infact nothing happens.

### Possible solutions?

In my research, I've come across this SO post - the only post that offers a solution of some sort solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67342928/unable-to-start-activity-from-onbackgroundmessage) (***which offers an Android specific solution only***).

**Solution 1:**

Use native code to override the [onMessageRecieved](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService#onMessageReceived(com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage)) in Android and call `startActivity()` from this service. See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService) for more info.

**Solution 2:**

Using [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications), create a notification which when clicked/activated opens the app. The problem with this solution is it remains a notification.

[image]

I've already got a custom call screen which specific requirements, but in essence I need to show something like the above when a FCM message comes through informing the user of a call - I'm unable to do this from an Isolate function (as discussed above).

**How can I achieve this?**

Answer (score 0):

try using https://pub.dev/packages/callkeep got this from the official docs of Agora https://docs.agora.io/en/signaling/develop/call-invite-notification?platform=android. So you might wanna look at it.